# The request body contains invalid JSON - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I got error The request body contains invalid JSON, even my body was a valid JSON
I use JSON.parse for converting my string to json
here is my body

`var formdata = JSON.parse('{"content":"this is a json sir"}')  console.log(formdata) var requestOptions = { method: 'DELETE', body: formdata, headers: myHeaders, redirect: 'follow' };`
and this my output on terminal still The request body contains invalid JSON :)
output in the picture

Comment: Hi Esa, Can you please share myHeaders object too?

Comment: Your string is **already** JSON. `JSON.parse` converts it to an Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `JSON.parse()` use `JSON.stringify()`

try this code.

```js
var formdata = JSON.stringify({content: "this is a json sir" });

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'DELETE',
  body: formdata,
  headers: {
      ...myHeaders,
     contentType: "application/json",
 },
  redirect: 'follow'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing JSON.parse you are sending an object, not a JSON string which I believe is what it is expecting.

If you change it to the below, it should work as expected. You will need to send a header with `content-type: application/json`

```
var formdata = '{"content":"this is a json sir"}'
console.log(formdata) 
var requestOptions = { method: 'DELETE', body: formdata, headers: myHeaders, redirect: 'follow' };
```